# Can't edit avatar. Sends me out after pressing edit avatar

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I wanted to edit my avatar on Xbox Live. I'm completely signed in. When ever I press customize avatar, or avatar store, it says the player signed out now exiting avatar store. Whenever I press the check mark, or button A or B, it sends me back to dashboard. Please help me. What do I do?